# Is this a legitimate substitution to solve the Mathieu equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My apologies if question is too applied, but it seemed to be a little too mathematically technical for the physics stack exchange.

This paper claims to have found an analytic solution to the Mathieu differntial equation (https://academic.oup.com/ptep/article/2020/4/043A01/5823816), which would be quite spectacular.

To keep the question focused, I wanted to ask about an early part of the paper, where the author simplifies
\begin{equation}
  \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + (a-2q\cos(2x)) y(x) = 0
\end{equation} by using the substitution $z=e^{ix}$. This substitution strikes me as odd, as even if we allow $x \in \mathbb{C}$, the domain of $z$ would only be the the punctured plane; this would seem problematic if we are to allow for initial conditions at $x=0$.

My question is the following: Does my concern make this substitution illegitimate? If the substitution is legitimate, does any sort of special handling of the $x=0$ case need to happen?

Also if anyone wants to go through the paper and point out anything else that seems odd, they are more than welcome.

Comment: The point $x=0$ maps to $z=1$, so that in itself is not a concern. Indeed, a Laurent series in $z$ is equivalent to a Fourier series in $x$.